# Having trouble with a form using ajax

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, jquery-mobile

Hello everyone, I'm new to jquery mobile and I'm having trouble figuring out how to do the following.

1) I need a dropdown/select menu that a user can select from.

2) After the user selects a value, he/she can press the submit button and get the miles for the trip from the link in the Ajax URL (jonsp file).  Here I would need to pass the value that the user selected in the form.

It seems simple enough but like I said, I'm new and below is as far as I got.

```
 <html>
   <head>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.4/jquery.mobile-1.4.4.min.css">
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.4/jquery.mobile-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
   </head>

   <!--BODY -->
   <body>
       <!-- PAGE -->
       <div data-role="page" id="form_page">
           <!-- HEADER -->
       <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false">   
       <h1>Header</h1>
        </div>
        <!-- END HEADER -->

        <!-- CONTENT -->
        <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
            <form method="get">
                <fieldset class="ui-field-contain">
                    <label for="cars">Select Day</label>
                    <select name="cars" id="cars" data-native-menu="false">
                        <option value="A">A</option>
                        <option value="B">B</option>
                        <option value="C">C</option>
                        <option value="D">D</option>
                        <option value="E">E</option>
                        <option value="F">F</option>
                        <option value="G">G</option>
                        <option value="H">H</option>
                    </select>
                </fieldset>
                <input type="submit" data-inline="true" value="Submit">
            </form>

            <div id="result">
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- END CONTENT -->

        <!-- FOOTER -->
        <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false"> <h1>Footer</h1> </div>
        <!-- END FOOTER -->
    </div> 
    <!-- END PAGE -->
</body>
<!-- END BODY -->
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#my_button").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: 'https://api.wmata.com/Rail.svc/json/jSrcStationToDstStationInfo?FromStationCode=A15&ToStationCode=A12&api_key=kfgpmgvfgacx98de9q3xazww',
            dataType: 'jsonp',
        }).success(function (data){
            $("#result").append($(data.StationToStationInfos[0].CompositeMiles));
        });
    }); 
});
</script>
 </html>
```

Comment: This really doesn't make sense.  If the question is unclear then how did the person that submitted the answer figure it out?  I can understand if I didn't get any answers or if I would have received requests for clarification.  Anyway, I just find it ridiculous that this was done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
// Catch form submission
$('form').on('submit', function(){
   // Make your AJAX call
   $.ajax({
      url: 'myUrl', // Your url
      method: $('form').attr('method'),
      dataType: 'jsonp',
      data: {cars: $('#cars').val()}, // Your data that you want to submit
      // data: $('form').serialize() if you have more than one data on your form
      success : function(jsonp) {
        // jsonp is the returned values from your backend application
        // MY CODE
        $("#result").html('');
        $("#result").append($(data.StationToStationInfos[0].CompositeMiles));
        // or easier  $("#result").html($(data.StationToStationInfos[0].CompositeMiles));
      }
   });

   // Prevent default submission
   return false;
});
```

Comment: Hi there, thank you for the quick response. It does work but if I click on submit multiple times it keeps appending the same value so the text looks something like this "5.375.375.375.375.375.375.37".  Is there any way to prevent this?

Comment: Just edited my answer

Comment: One last question.  What if I wanted to get rid of the "Submit" button and just let the javascript execute once the user has made a choice from the dropdown menu.  Is that possible? or do I really need the "Submit" button?

Comment: Just use this `$('#cars').on('change', function(){$('form').submit();});`

Answer (score 0):

You need to read the value from the select within your click function.

`var value = $("selector").val();`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `serialize()` [method](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) to get the data that contains the form.

```
var dataForm = $("form").serialize();
```

Then in your `AJAX` you need to set the data that you want to send to the server and specify the method:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://api.wmata.com/Rail.svc/json/jSrcStationToDstStationInfo?FromStationCode=A15&ToStationCode=A12&api_key=kfgpmgvfgacx98de9q3xazww',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        data: dataForm,
        method: "post",
    }).success(function (data){
        $("#result").append($(data.StationToStationInfos[0].CompositeMiles));
    });
```